# Update SQS messages If there is error while processing

Tags: python, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

Hi I have two lambdas eg: L1 and L2. L1 creates SQS message and send it to my SQS queue.
example:

```
queue.send_message(MessageBody='boto3', MessageAttributes={
    'Author': {
        'StringValue': 'Daniel',
        'DataType': 'String'
    }
})
```

L2 receives this message from SQS for further processing now if this message fails in processing
this message will move to the DLQ where another lambda L3 will do failure processing.
What I'm trying to do is when message fails L2 will add message attribute `(Error: failed due to xyz)` in message and then this message will move to DLQ.

But not getting how to do it as far as I know SQS messages are immutable. Can anyone help me out how to do this or is there any alternative.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. The message attributes of an SQS message are immutable once the message has been sent to the queue. The SQS Query API (used by all client libraries) has no support for modifying a message in the queue, other than to change its visibility timeout.